# Crashlytics draining bandwidth and upload unknown huge amount of data

Tags: crashlytics

I was doing a check for my internet usage. After digging, I found out that Crashlytics is using my network heavily - uploading 6GB of data in the past month! I use Fabric for my apps and Xcode simulator all the time so this should be it. Here's my log:

> Connection to cm.crashlytics.com
>   HTTPS, 11 MB in / 382 MB out

There were many such instances such as 100MB per hour upload. What is Crashlytics trying to upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. If you're building on iOS, then a new dSYM is being created for your app each time you build. Those are then uploaded to our servers so that we can process your crash reports. You can add conditional logic to prevent dSYMs from being uploaded as [documented](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html#conditional-dsym-upload):

```
releaseConfig="Release"

if [ "$releaseConfig" = "${CONFIGURATION}" ]; then
    echo "Running Crashlytics"
    ./Fabric.framework/run <your_api_key_here>
fi
```

Comment: Yes Thanks Mike for your answer i also got your email and i was going to post it here which i saw u already posted :)

Comment: Mike i still have the problem . what do u suggest ?

Comment: How often are you doing release builds?

Comment: Once a week mostly.

Comment: Hmm, I'll need to look at logs then. Can you zip up this folder and send it over to our email discussion?
 ~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/com.crashlytics.mac/v3/active